# How to implement communication between siblings in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got vue app with following structure:
"blackout" component for poping up modals and router-view for all sub-menues.
Those are sibling (located at one level).

```
<blackout v-if="this.popup.currentPopup"></blackout>
     ....
<router-view class="folder">
  ...child-component with get request displaying data
</router-view>
```

There is a saving button for sending data with post method in dynamic loaded component at "blackout"(:is directive). After click save button I need to re-fetch data at "router-view"'s child component.
My question is how to notify sibling component that sibling-modal have made a post request and was closed.

After some researches I find out some: event-bus (antipattern), watching store state (keep modal's state in pinia), communicate through this.$root (available only in vue2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, there are a bunch of different ways to achieve what you want:

1. this.$root is arguably pure evil. It breaks Vue principles and makes communication between components difficult to understand and debug.
2. Event bus is a very controversial pattern, but you can use it (check out Hetal N answer). Also Vue 3 doesn't have this api, so you'll have to use some third party library or write your own event emitter.
3. Store like Pinia generally is a much better solution. It is easy to debug and test.

However the most obvious and direct approach might be to communicate via parent component using props and emits:

```js
// Parent.vue
// template
<Foo @success="isRequestSuccessful = true" />
<Bar :isRequestSuccesfull="isRequestSuccessful" />

// script
const isRequestSuccessful = ref(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Component communication plays major role in Frontend Famrworks like `Vue.js`.

You can pass data from one component to another component at `same level` using `Event bus` and `state management` (Majorly used [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern)).

```
export default {
    name: "DemoComponent"
    methods: {
        sendMessage() {
            this.$root.$emit("messafe from Demo component", argument1, argument2)
        }
    }
}

export default {
    name: "TestComponent"
    methods: {
        this.$root.$on("Message from Demo", (argument1, argument2) => {
            console.log("Arg 1" + argument1);
            console.log("Arg 1" + argument2);
        }
    }
}
```

> Avoid using Event Bus for large scal applications instead use `Vuex`
> As $on, $emit such methods have been removed from Vue 3 so it might
> throw errors in console.

More details can be found [here](https://medium.com/js-dojo/component-communication-in-vue-js-ca8b591d7efa) & [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-to-pass-data-between-components/)